# I need a shorthand way to combine Maps in groovy with slightly different results than +

Tags: groovy, dictionary

NOTE: This can be done as a method call or an operator override pretty easily, I am looking for an intrinsic one-line solution that I don't have to carry around in a library.

When you combine(add) Maps, you get a result like this:

```
println [a:1,c:3] + [a:2]
// prints {a=2, c=3}
```

I seem to keep needing results more like:

```
{a=[1, 2], c=[3]}
```

In other words, something that combines all the values from identical keys in the Maps.

Is there an operator or simple function call that does this, because doing it myself always seems to break my stride a little.  It seems like the * operator might do this nicely, but it doesn't.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: How do you want the result to be for these two maps? `[ a:1, c:10 ]` and `[ b:1, a:3 ]`

Comment: tim's reasoning is correct, I'd like [a:[1,3], b:[1],c:[10]] and I'd rather not go multi-line (I'd rather keep it functional style because I'm enjoying that).  This seems to come up all the time... I'm really surprised it's not just a built-in.

Comment: @cfrick it's strange how two people have now edited this question to change the way groovy prints results into--well NOT the way groovy prints results.  Try typing in "[[a:1]]" into groovy and see that you get "[{a=1}]".  Since I explicitly changed the wording to "Groovy displays" after the last guy changed it I'm utterly confused by this edit.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative (adding it to the `*` operator on Maps)

```
def a = [ a:1, c:10 ]
def b = [ b:1, a:3 ]

Map.metaClass.multiply = { Map other ->
    (delegate.keySet() + other.keySet()).inject( [:].withDefault { [] } ) { m, v ->
        if (delegate[v] != null) { m[v] << delegate[v] }
        if (other[v] != null) { m[v] << other[v] }
        m
    }
}

assert a * b == [a:[1, 3], c:[10], b:[1]]
```

Came up with this as well, but it's late and there are probably better, shorter ways

```
def a = [ a:1, c:10 ] 
def b = [ b:1, a:3 ]

[a,b]*.collect {k,v -> [(k):v]}
      .flatten()
      .groupBy { it.keySet()[0]}
      .inject([:].withDefault{[]}) {m,v->
          m << [(v.key):v.value[v.key]]
      }
  ​​
```

Comment: You beat me to it. :) I was trying to modify `plus`.

Comment: In the previous version elements not present in the second map were added to a list.

Comment: Isn't that what was wanted?  A combination of all the element in both maps, with their values in lists

Comment: I don't think so - *In other words, something that combines all the values from identical keys in the Maps.*

Comment: Hmmm... Yeah, I read that as "Combines the values **when** the keys are identical" (but still returns those that differ)

Comment: I read as the behavior of `plus` is required as is with a small exception of collecting the overrides instead of overriding them. :)

Comment: Plus would give you a, b and c wouldn't it?

Comment: Tim, your understanding of my question is correct.  I was considering overriding "*" (and probably will, this is awesome) but I'm using this for scripting and don't always have a personal library available... was hoping there was a built-in function that did this easily (groupBy is so close!)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing came to my mind, so I start the bidding with this:

```
m1 = [a:1, c:666]; m2 = [a:2, b:42]
result = [:].withDefault{[]}
[m1,m2].each{ it.each{ result[it.key] << it.value } }
assert result == [a:[1,2], b:[42], c:[666]]
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I do now (In fact, almost exact).  I was hoping for a short-hand functional version like "assert [m1,m2].regroup() == [a:[1,2], b:[42], c:[666]]".  By the way I LOVE .withDefault!  Considered writing a library function that regroups a bunch but then you're lugging a library around with you!